# Creating a fixed navigation bar in a react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a navigation bar and when users click on any of the links it should display
the component tied to this link.

How do I put these together such that the links stay permanently on my main page and 
the content changes once the link is clicked.

```
        import React, {Component} from 'react';

        class Main extends Component{
            render(){
                return(
                    <div>
                       <ul>
                        <li>Link 1</li>
                        <li>Link 2</li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        export default Main;
```

Here is my index.js file which shows my route

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
        import promise from 'redux-promise';
        import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
        import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

        import reducers from './reducers';
        import ProductsIndex from './components/products_index';
        import ProductsNew from './components/products_new';
        import Main from './components/main';


        const middleware = [promise]; 
        const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose; 
        const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware)); 
        const configureStore = (initialState) => createStore(reducers, initialState, enhancer); 


        ReactDOM.render(
          <Provider store={configureStore()}>
           <Router>
            <div>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/products/new" component={ProductsNew} /> 
                <Route path="/" component={ProductsIndex} />
              </Switch>      
            </div>
           </Router>
          </Provider>
          , document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main component:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

    class Main extends Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                   <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Link 1</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/products/new">Link 2</Link></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Main;
```

index.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import promise from 'redux-promise';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

    import reducers from './reducers';
    import ProductsIndex from './components/products_index';
    import ProductsNew from './components/products_new';
    import Main from './components/main';


    const middleware = [promise]; 
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose; 
    const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware)); 
    const configureStore = (initialState) => createStore(reducers, initialState, enhancer); 


    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={configureStore()}>
       <Router>
        <div>
          <Main/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/products/new" component={ProductsNew} /> 
            <Route path="/" component={ProductsIndex} />
          </Switch>      
        </div>
       </Router>
      </Provider>
      , document.querySelector('#root'));
```